# How many roots exist for $y=sec(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, probability-distributions, random-variables, roots, random

In the interval $( - \pi ,\ \pi ]$.There are 2 roots exist mentioned in the book. Could anyone please explain how?

Exact question from book : Let $Y=\sec X$ .Compute $f_Y(y)$ in terms of $f_X(x)$ .What is $f_Y(y)$ when $f_X(x)$ is uniform in $[ −π,π )$ ?

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle y = \sec(x) ={1\over\cos(x)}$. The only way a fraction equals $0$ is if the numerator equals zero. This is impossible since $1\ne0$, which implies there are no real roots at all.

Comment: For y >1 ,there are 2 solution exists mentioned in the book. Actually the question belongs to Random variable from Q.# 3.12 from
Probability, Statistics, and Random Processes for Engineers, 4th Edition-Henry Stark and John Woods

Comment: The likelihood someone here has the textbook is low. If you want further insight, are you able to provide the context of the problem listed? Edit your post with the exact question, word-for-word.

Comment: Okay, Q .Let Y=secX .Compute $ f_{Y}(y) $ in terms of $ f_{X}(x) $ .What is $ f_{Y}(y) $ when $ f_{X}(x) $ is uniform in [ $ - \pi, \pi $ )

Answer (score 1):

$$\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x}$$

Obviously it is impossible for $\sec x$ to become $0$ because $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ can never reach $0$. In fact, since the range of $\cos x$ is $y \in [-1, 1]$, the range of $\sec x$ becomes $y \in (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, +\infty)$. Hence, there are no real roots.

Answer (score 0):

Hint #1: Draw the graph (or use a graphing program) of $\sec (x) \ \text {(or} \  \dfrac {1}{\cos (x)})$.

Hint #2: Viewing the graph, where is $\sec (x)$ undefined?

Comment: Are you meant solutions are  $x1=cos^{-1} \frac{1} {y} $ and   $ x2= -cos^{-1} \frac{1} {y} $

Comment: I've re-written the hints above.  You may also want to see the solution offered by KM101 below.

Comment: My book solution is something i mentioned above .